# Concatinating strings to a single string in python

Tags: string, text, save

I have a code that save some string to some text (work correctly). I want to concatinate the string to one string and save it to one file in one time.

```
`np.savetxt(f'{PTH}/pointwise_layer_{number_layer}_channel_{ch}.txt',np.transpose(np.squeeze(layers[number_layer].weights[1][:,:,:,ch],0)))`
```

I have wrote this code, but it does not work:

`pointStr = np.squeeze(layers[number_layer].weights[1][:,:,:,ch],0) + pointStr`

Do you know the correct code?